# How can I add numbers from a given array to a linked list without allowing duplicates?

Tags: arrays, c, linked-list

I gotta write a function that takes the number from a given array and creates a linked list with them without allowing duplicates, my code works for adding the numbers but when I print the list I still get duplicate `4`, it's like the function doesn't check if the number is already in the list and I can't find what's wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} SNode;

typedef SNode *TNode;

void makeList(int arr[], int len, TNode *head);
void printList(TNode head);

void main() {
    TNode head = NULL;
    int array[5] = { 1, 2, 4, 4, 8 };
    
    makeList(array, 5, &head);
    
    printList(head);
}

void makeList(int arr[], int len, TNode *head) {
    TNode tmp1, tmp2 = *head;
    int i, j;
    
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (tmp2 == NULL) {
            tmp1 = (TNode)malloc(sizeof(SNode));
            tmp1->data = arr[i];
            tmp1->next = *head;
            *head = tmp1;
        }

        while (tmp2 != NULL) {
            if (tmp2->data != arr[i]) {
                tmp1 = (TNode)malloc(sizeof(SNode));
                tmp1->data = arr[i];
                tmp1->next = *head;
                *head = tmp1;
            }
            tmp2 = tmp2->next;
        }   
    }
}

void printList(TNode head) {
    TNode tmp = head;
        
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", tmp->data);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that tmp2 will always be NULL. I don't see a path where it will ever get set to anything else.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I set (tmp2 = *head) after (*head = tmp1;) I get more numbers now but they're all duplicates

Comment: You'd probably find it easier to create two new functions: bool number_exists_in_list(TNode list, int number), and void add_number_to_list(TNode *list, int number). This would be much easier to understand, and much easier to write. I'd leave writing those functions to you though, it's your homework.

Comment: *"it's like the function doesn't check if the number is already in the list"* - Then make a separate find function.

Comment: Just a few notes:
* The pointer to the next object should be the first element of your `struct`. This is conventional, and makes the voodoo behind generic functions like `insque` and `remque` possible.
* You should rearrange the parameters to makeList so that the length comes before the array. then you can enable possible bounds checking by doing `makeList(int len, int arr[static len], ...)`
* Since `len` represents a size, you probably want it to be a `size_t`

Answer (score 2):

1. Never ever hide pointers behind the typedefs. It is a very bad practice.
2. I do not think that you need great performance, you can traverse the linked list
3. Use the correct type for sizes
4. Use object not types in `sizeof`s
5. Split the problem into smaller tasks (functions)
6. `void main` is wrong.
7. Do not cast the result of the `malloc`. If the code does not compile it means that you compile it using a **C++** compiler wich is not correct.
8. Avoid double pointers and side effects if possible. Use function return values (instead of void func)

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} SNode;


SNode *makeList (const int arr[], size_t len, SNode *head);
void printList (SNode *head);

int main(void)
{
    SNode *head, *tmp;
    int array[5] = {1,2,4,4,8};
    int array2[5] = {6,2,4,7,9};
    
    head = makeList (array, 5, NULL);
    if(head) printList (head);
    printf("-------------------------\n");
    tmp = makeList (array2, 5, head);
    if(tmp)
    {
        head = tmp;
        printList (head);
    }
   
/* free the list */
        
}

int isInList(const int val, const SNode *head)
{
    int result = 0;
    while(head) 
    {
        if(head -> data == val)
        {
            result = 1;
            break;
        }
        head = head -> next;
    }
    return result;
}

SNode *add(int val, SNode *last)
{
    if(!last) last = malloc(sizeof(*last));
    else
    {
        last -> next = malloc(sizeof(*last));
        last = last -> next;
    }
    if(last)
    {
        last -> data = val;
        last -> next = NULL;
    }
    return last;
}

SNode *findLast(const SNode *head)
{
    if(head)
    {
        while(head -> next) head = head -> next;
    }
    return (SNode *)head;
}

SNode *makeList (const int arr[], size_t len, SNode *head)
{
    SNode *last = findLast(head);
    while(len--)
    {
        if(!isInList(*arr, head))
        {
            last = add(*arr, last);
            if(!head) head = last;
            if(!last) break;
        }
        arr++;
    }
    return head;
}

void printList(SNode *head)
{
    while(head) {printf("%d\n", head -> data);head = head -> next;}
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1Wssf6Gz9

Comment: You can get rid of the if statements in "if (head) while(head)" in isInList() and printList(), and remove a layer of nesting in the process.

Comment: @pmacfarlane good spot :)

Comment: You do not free the lists and since you overwrite `head`, you have a memory leak. `last -> data` is unusual, `last->data` is more common and probably more readable for most programmers. Cramming more than one statement on a single line is not recommended. Missing `#include` lines.

Comment: @0___________: actually, there is no need for `tmp`:  `head = makeList (array2, 5, head);` is fine in all cases. The downside of this implementation is you cannot detect insertion failure.